# jQuery animation from the center

Tags: jquery

I've to make a little loading animation (body background black, a little line coming from the middle to right/left then the little line height up to top/bottom).

There is what I've made so far, I've try some things, but didn't found a good way to do it, that's why i'm there ^^

Here is what I've made so far :

```js
// Functions
let loading = function (duration) {
    $('.loader > div').animate({
            'width':'100%'
        }, duration, function () {
            $('.loader > div').animate({
               'height':'100%'
            }, duration, function () {
                $('.loader').css({'display':'none'});
                $('#content').css({'display':'block'});
            });
        });
};

$(document).ready(function($) {

    // Loading
    loading(1000);

});
```

```css
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 9999999999;
}

.loader > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 1px;
}

#content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="content">     
  <div class="content">
    Page content
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like the little white line to come from the center and go to right / left to width: 100%;
and after that, I would like this line to come from the center to top / bottom to height: 100% then show the content of the page, I didn't found a way to do it smoothly :/

Thanks for your help ^^

Théo

Comment: Here's a quick way to center that loading line: http://jsfiddle.net/d76u9c0q/2/. Just give that loader div `width: 0` and set it to `margin: 0 auto` with `left: 0` and `right: 0`. I'll get the second part of your question soon unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @DanielD Thanks for your answer, yeah already tryed that, the problem come from that I've to move dynamically the left (or right) to make the line to width 100%, and didn't find how to :/

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle? You can have that loading line be dynamic since you are using percentages. so it could be 10px width to 1000px wide. Here's a different approach with getting the loading div to the top of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/d76u9c0q/9/

Comment: @DanielD Thanks you, that exactly, what I wanted :P

Comment: Nice. I'll write up an answer quick. Also check this one out since it does what you asked: http://jsfiddle.net/d76u9c0q/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close here. Since you are using animate, you can use callbacks from each animation to achieve what you are after. I'd handle this task like such:

Example 1

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

 // Functions
let loading = function (duration) {
  $('.loader > div').animate({
      'width':'100%'
    }, duration, function () {
      $('.loader > div').animate({
       'top': 0,
        'height':'100%'
      }, duration, function () {
        $('.loader').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
  };

  // Loading
  loading(1000);

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.loader > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="content">     
  <div class="content">
    Page content
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

 // Functions
let loading = function (duration) {
  $('.loader > div').animate({
      'width':'100%'
    }, duration, function () {
      $('.loader > div').animate({
       'top': 0,
      }, duration, function () {
      $('.loader > div').animate({
        'height':'100%'
      }, duration, function () {
        $('.loader').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#content').fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
  });
  
  }

  // Loading
  loading(1000);

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.loader > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="content">     
  <div class="content">
    Page content
  </div>
</div>
```